# LSP4J: How to make language server request something from client

Tags: typescript, scala, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm working on a Language Server written in Scala using LSP4J. I was following the docs from both VS Code and the LSP4J and got to the point where I could send notifications back and forth between client and server. I have also managed to make the client request things from the server and to then work with them. However, I've not completely managed to go the other way around. I.e., I can get the server to make requests to the client, but these requests never complete.

To give you some context, this is what I did:

1. Implemented a status bar item for the VS Code extension.
2. Registered a command that would send a notification to the server when the item is clicked.
3. Implemented a handler for that notification on the server side.
4. Have that handler send a request to the client.
5. Implemented a handler for that request on the client side.

So far, so good. I can trace each step and know that everything is executed as I expect. Now, on the server side, I should get back a `CompletableFuture`. In my understanding of things, this `CompletableFuture` should eventually complete with the value I returned by the request handler (on the client side).

Below are the relevant parts of the code described above.

```
trait IdeLanguageClient extends LanguageClient {

  //...

  //This is the request sent to the client
  @JsonRequest("SomeRequest")
  def s2c_request(): CompletableFuture[String]
}
```

```
class ExampleLanguageServer() extends LanguageClientAware {
  private var client: Option[IdeLanguageClient] = None

  //...  


  //This is the handler for the notification the client sends after clicking on the status bar.
  @JsonNotification("sbi")
  def c2s_notification(): Unit = {
    client match {
      case Some(c) =>
        val completable_future = c.s2c_request()
        while(!fut.isDone){
          println("sleepy")
          Thread.sleep(1000)   // This goes on for ever!!
        }
        val s = fut.get()
        println(s)
    }
  }

  override def connect(client: LanguageClient): Unit = {
    println("client is connected")
    this.client = Some(client.asInstanceOf[IdeLanguageClient])
  }
}
```

```
export function activate(context: ExtensionContext) {

  //...

  // Create the language client.
  client = new LanguageClient(
    'languageServerExample',
    'Language Server Example',
    startServer,
    clientOptions
  );
        
  createStatusBarItem();

  // Handler for the server's request
  client.onReady().then(ready => {
      client.onRequest("SomeRequest", () => {
          "Some Responce to the request"
      });
  });
    
  // Start the client. This will also launch the server
  client.start();

  function createStatusBarItem() {...}
  // Invokes the jars of the language server
  function startServer(): Promise<StreamInfo> {...}
}
```

The critical part is the while loop `c2s_notification`. In my understanding, the future should eventually (given the minuscule task, pretty much immediately) be done and yield the value returned by the `onRequest` handle. Instead, the loop just goes on printing "sleep" once per second. Did I misundestand something? Or am I just doing something wrong?

I hope the problem is stated clearly enough and that it includes all the necessary information.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. I thought that `CompletableFuture`s could be treated like `Future`s. This is apparently not the case. Instead, the asynchronous computation of `join` -ing (or `get` -ting) the results from a `CompletableFuture` must itseld be wrapped by a `Future`.

I.e., replacing the critical part around the while loop in the `c2sNotification` with the following does the trick:

```
client match {
  case Some(c) =>
    val f: Future[String] = Future {
      val cf: CompletableFuture[String] = c.s2c_request()
      val s = cf.join()
      s
    }
    f.onComplete({
      case Success(s) => println(s)
      case Failure(e) => println(e)
    })
}
```